# Replication acknowledgement in PostgreSQL + BDR

Tags: multithreading, postgresql, replicaset, postgresql-bdr

I'm using libpq C Library for testing PG + BDR replica set. I'd like to get acknowledgement of the CRUD operations' replication. My purpose is to make my own log of the replication time in milliseconds or if possible in microseconds.

The program:
Starts 10-20 threads witch separate connections, each thread makes 1000-5000 cycles of basic CRUD operations on three tables.

Which would be the best way? 
Parsing some high verbosity logs if they have proper data with time stamp or in my C api I should start N thread (N = {number of nodes} - {the master I'm connected to}) after every CRUD op. and query the nodes for the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get replay confirmation of individual xacts easily. The system keeps track of the log sequence number replayed by peer nodes but not what transaction IDs those correspond to, since it doesn't care.

What you seem to want is near-synchronous or semi-synchronous replication. There's some work coming there for 9.6 that will hopefully benefit BDR in time, but that's well in the future.

In the mean time you can see the log sequence number as `restart_lsn` in `pg_replication_slots`. This is not the position the replica has replayed to, but it's the oldest point it might have to restart replay at after a crash.

You can see the other LSN fields like `replay_location` only when a replica is connected in `pg_stat_replication`. Unfortunately in 9.4 there's no easy way to see which slot in `pg_replication_slots` is associated with which active connection in `pg_stat_replication` (fixed in 9.5, but BDR is based on 9.4 still). So you have to use the `application_name` set by BDR if you want to pick out individual nodes, and it's ... "interesting" to parse. Also often truncated.

You can get the current LSN of the server you committed an xact on *after committing it* by calling `SELECT pg_current_xlog_location();` which will return a value like `0/19E0F060` or whatever. You can then look that value up in the `pg_stat_replication` of peer nodes until you see that the `replay_location` for the node you committed on has reached or passed the LSN you captured immediately after commit.

It's not perfect. There could be other work done between when you commit and when you capture the server's current LSN. There's no way around that, but at worst you wait slightly too long. If you're using BDR you shouldn't be caring about micro or even milliseconds anyway, since it's an *asynchronous* replication solution.

The principles are pretty similar to measuring replication lag for normal physical standby servers, so I suggest reading some docs on that. Except that [`pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-RECOVERY-INFO-TABLE) won't work for logical replication, so you can't get lag using that, you have to use the LSNs and do your own timing client-side.

Comment: Well that's an unexpectedly overall answer! Thanks a lot Craig!